# Why does the function always return 0? (C)

Tags: c, return, return-value

Below is the code for a function I wrote that calculates the income tax when the taxable amount is passed through.

Essentially, the code should calculate the amount of tax the person has to pay based on the following:

- Taxable income amount up to 34,500 is taxed at 20%
- Taxable income amount from 34,501 to 150,000 is taxed at 40%
- Taxable income amount over 150,000 is taxed at 45%

---

```
float compute_annual_income_tax ( float taxableIncome ) {
    float t = 0;
    if (taxableIncome <= 0)
     t = 0 * taxableIncome;
    else if (taxableIncome > 0 && taxableIncome <= 34500)
     t = (taxableIncome * 0.2);
    else if (taxableIncome > 34500 && taxableIncome <= 150000) {
     float t2;
     t2 = taxableIncome - 34500;
     t = ((34500 * 0.2) + (t2 * 0.4));
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 150000) {
     float t2, t3;
     t3 = taxableIncome - 150000;
     t2 = 150000 - 34500;
     t = ((34500 * 0.2) + (t2 * 0.4) + (t3 * 0.45));
    }
    return t;
}
```

The code is tested using the following:

> gcc -lm -std=c99 -o

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding the following code: 
`if (taxableIncome < 0)`
    `t  = taxableIncome * 0.20`
...

Comment: however, this is obviously wrong as the taxableIncome nor the annual income tax can be 0. thus, the testing program used must be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is. You need to check the input to the function and the way you use the output. you can simply insert a line at the beginning of the function to print the input and insert a line at the end to print the output

```
float compute_annual_income_tax ( float taxableIncome ) {
  float t = 0;
  printf("taxable income: %f\n", taxableIncome);
  ...
  printf("income tax: %f\n", t);
  return t;
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and the test still failed. The test program doesn't allow any interactive components to be used (i.e. scanf and printf). 
However, adding the lines of code you gave above, resulted in showing the different values used to test the program.
The function fails when -9488 is entered. Therefore I think that the issue lies within the test program.
I don't see how an annual income tax is possible when the taxable Income is a negative

Comment: This is what was shown when I added the printf statements:
`test.c:85:test_taxable_income:PASS

taxableIncome: 77533.000000

income tax: 24113.199219

taxableIncome: 80927.000000

income tax: 25470.800781

taxableIncome: 147793.000000


income tax: 52217.199219
taxableIncome: 73536.000000
income tax: 22514.400391
taxableIncome: 113123.500000
income tax: 38349.398438
taxableIncome: -9488.000000
income tax: 0.000000
test.c:38:test_annual_income_tax:FAIL: Expected -1897.6 Was 0`

Comment: test_taxable_income:PASS   
test_annual_income_tax:FAIL